# Couldnt open connection to Outlook server in Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, outlook

Using Nexus 5 running on 4.4.4 not able to connect. Password and username are correct(checked a 100 times), cleared the cache but still not able to connect to outlook server. I'm getting 3g data speed too.

Comment: What server? Email? Google accout? Play Store?

Comment: microsoft outlook.